# What is the meaning of the Hmmer profile?

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I want to understand what the hmmer Profile used in [hmmer](http://hmmer.org/).

consider the profile

```
HMMER2.0  [converted from 3.1b2]
NAME  aRNH_profile
LENG  121
ALPH  Amino
RF    no
CS    no
MAP   yes
NSEQ  34
DATE  Tue Apr 26 21:24:57 2016
XT       -8455     -4  -1000  -1000  -8455     -4  -8455     -4
NULT        -4  -8455
NULE       656  -1722     98    419   -333    475  -1125    239    250    947  -1073   -271    -50   -338    114    451    113    430  -2131   -717
HMM        A      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      K      L      M      N      P      Q      R      S      T      V      W      Y    
         m->m   m->i   m->d   i->m   i->i   d->m   d->d   b->m   m->e
           -6      *  -7932
     1    -214   -916   -565    694    862  -1448    512   -838    115  -1042    170   1348  -1481    369   -158   -290   -159   -625    -52   1675     1
     -    -210   -336    220    -37   -342    377     73   -669    210   -511   -732    404    423     70     27    439    205   -414   -161   -176
     -     -18  -6890  -7932   -894  -1115   -701  -1378    -18      *
     2     285    990  -2213  -1678   2305  -1819   -698    219  -1289   -140    545  -1167  -1835   -973  -1322   -424   1025    762   -559    377     2
     -    -210   -336    220    -37   -342    377     73   -669    210   -511   -732    404    423     70     27    439    205   -414   -161   -176
     -     -18  -6890  -7932   -894  -1115   -701  -1378      *      *
[....]
```

what exactly does each component mean? By definition a HMM $\lambda$ consist of an alphabet $V$ in my case twenty amino acids. Different states $S$ in our case main, insertion and deletion (beginning and end). And two probability matrices of state transitions and emission in certain state.

now if I look at the profile I can see that it has the allowed transitions
`m->m   m->i   m->d   i->m   i->i   d->m   d->d   b->m   m->e` 
and all the amino acids, but what does each row in the table mean. I checked the manual from the documentation and it says rather ironically

> If you were to look at this file (and you don’t have to – it’s
>   intended for HMMER’s consumption, not yours), you’d see [part of my output]

are these number translations of the probabilities in $[0,1]$  into another interval $[-x,+y]$? what is the meaning of the three rows under `A 1`

```
-124  
-210
 -18
```

Is this the transition matrix? It would be great if someone could explain this  or point to the correct reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial in the [documentation](http://eddylab.org/software/hmmer3/3.1b2/Userguide.pdf) does indeed state what you quoted but a full description of the file format is given in Section 8 of the documentation, starting on page 106.

To summarise, as you noted, the number columns A-K is the alphabet size (the number of amino acids). The number of rows underneath is the number of nodes, which corresponds to the number of match states. The three numbers (-214, -210 and -18 in your example) are: the match emission, insert emission, and state transition values.

Caveat: The HMMER profile HMM format changes frequently between HMMER versions (even between minor versions) so there is no guarantee this information is correct for all the older file formats.

---

Quoting the relevant part of the documentation on page 109:

> **main model section**
>
> All the remaining fields are mandatory. The first
> two lines in the main model section are atypical.‡ They contain
> information for the core model’s BEGIN node. This is stored as model
> node 0, and match state 0 is treated as the BEGIN state. The begin
> state is mute, so there are no match emission probabilities. The first
> line is the insert 0 emissions. The second line contains the
> transitions from the begin state and insert state 0. These seven
> numbers are: B → M1, B → I0, B → D1; I0 → M1, I0 → I0; then a 0.0 and
> a ’*’, because by convention, nonexistent transitions from the
> nonexistent delete state 0 are set to log 1 = 0 and log 0 = −∞ = ‘*’.
>
> The remainder of the model has three lines per node, for M nodes
> (where M is the number of match states, as given by the LENG line).
> These three lines are (K is the alphabet size in residues):
>
> **Match emission line**
>
> The first field is the node number (1 . . . M). The
> parser verifies this number as a consistency check (it expects the
> nodes to come in order). The next K numbers for match emissions, one
> per symbol, in alphabetic order. The next field is the MAP annotation
> for this node. If MAP was yes in the header, then this is an integer,
> representing the alignment column index for this match state
> (1..alen); otherwise, this field is ‘-’. The next field is the CONS
> consensus residue for this node. If CONS was yes in the header, then
> this is a single character, representing the consensus residue
> annotation for this match state; otherwise, this field is ‘-’. The
> next field is the RF annotation for this node. If RF was yes in the
> header, then this is a single character, representing the reference
> annotation for this match state; otherwise, this field is ‘-’. The
> next field is the MM mask value for this node. If MM was yes in the
> header, then this is a single ’m’ character, indicating that the
> position was identified as a masked position during model
> construction; otherwise, this field is ‘-’. The next field is the CS
> annotation for this node. If CS was yes, then this is a single
> character, representing the consensus structure at this match state;
> otherwise this field is ‘-’.
>
> **Insert emission line**
>
> The K fields on this
> line are the insert emission scores, one per symbol, in alphabetic
> order.
>
> **State transition line**
>
> The seven fields on this line are the
> transitions for node k, in the order shown by the transition header
> line: Mk → Mk+1, Ik, Dk+1; Ik → Mk+1, Ik; Dk → Mk+1, Dk+1. For
> transitions from the final node M, match state M + 1 is interpreted as
> the END state E, and there is no delete state M + 1; therefore the
> final Mk → Dk+1 and Dk → Dk+1 transitions are always * (zero
> probability), and the final Dk → Mk+1 transition is always 0.0
> (probability 1.0).

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I missed the later chapters. Sorry that was too quick of me.